# Prevent IReadOnlyCollection<T> to have default item

Tags: c#, collections

Is there an immutable collection that prohibits initialization with default values?

For instance:

```
var newObjects = new MyObject[]
        {
           default
        }
```

The `MyObject` class has a Copy method that throws an error when the parameter is set to default

```
public MyObject Clone()
    {
        return new MyObject(ShortName, Name);
    }
```

The newObjects variable iterates through the entire array and attempts to copy. However, since the only item in the array is set to default, it crashes. Is there a way to prevent this issue using a specific collection?

This is my example method:

```
public IEnumerable<MyObject> CopyObjects(IReadOnlyCollection<MyObject> newObjects)
    {
        var newLst = new List<MyObject>(); 
        foreach (var o in newObjects)
        {
            newLst.Add(o.Copy());
        }

        return newLst;
    }
```

Comment: What Am I missing here? Looks like this should solve your problem:  `CopyObjects(IReadOnlyCollection<MyObject> newObjects) => newObjects.Where(o => o is not null).Select(o => o.Copy());`

Comment: Please make your code compilable - what is `Copy` in `newObjects.Copy()`? Why are you calling `newLst.All`?

Comment: @GuruStron All was an typo. Replaced it with Add. The Copy method is available in my post.

Comment: Was this meant to read `VARIABLE.Copy()`? Please give us actual code, this isn't helpful.

Comment: @SteffenSkaraas should not it be `VARIABLE.Clone()` instead of `newObjects.Copy()`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled 
Certainly, implementing this can address the issue I'm encountering. However, is this a implementation you want to be using all over your project?

Comment: @GuruStron Another typo on my behalf. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean? This is a simple, straight forward way to do it. Why not use that whenever you need to?

Comment: What Zohar suggests is certainly the safest option to do everywhere. Always code defensively.

Comment: I understand that the solution that @ZoharPeled proposes is good solution. However, my question was more centered around whether there exists a collection that could prevent this. It's worth noting that my current code already ensures the prevention of default values being added by users. I dont want to clutter my colleciton inputs with a where clause. Thank you for the proposal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there an immutable collection that prohibits initialization with default values?

No, because it has nothing to do with collections but with the language itself. If `MyObject` is a reference type then you can leverage [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) in combination with [`TreatWarningsAsErrors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings#treatwarningsaserrors) compilation option to mitigate the issue to some extent:

```
var newObjects = new MyObject[]
{
   default // warning CS8625: Cannot convert null literal to non-nullable reference type.
};

class MyObject{}
```

Demo [@sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQ65IJwAoBEgPBuAg+/gJQDc66AbgIZgAEUApgO4DyARgFYsDGwAM6MAvM3aMAsgE9ufQQG0AuugDe6RloAmLAGZ0IAG2CMA9GcZsGUAJZQA5owDCAZQAcANgQBWEC7ooKAB7U35gqBoWMFMoYyNGI1tgaLoE4GDmCIBaOKMjOi4jFkYwfWiWKH4S4BkABxYAOnQAXyoMNERpOV4BYDUWzS1hrXQgA==)

Other options:

- filtering out nulls/defaults:

  ```
  IEnumerable<MyObject> CopyObjects(IReadOnlyCollection<MyObject> newObjects) 
     => newObjects
      .Where(obj => obj is not null)
      .Select(obj => obj.Clone())
      .ToList();
  ```

  you can update the code to manage the default value if it is not/not only null check.
- checking before calling `Clone` if the value is default one and returning default in this case. For example using [Null-conditional operator `?.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) which will return `null` in case of `null`:

  ```
  IEnumerable<MyObject> CopyObjects(IReadOnlyCollection<MyObject> newObjects) 
     => newObjects
      .Select(obj => obj?.Clone()) 
      .ToList();
  ```
- custom [Roslyn analyzer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-to-write-a-roslyn-analyzer/)

Comment: Just to clarify, your CopyObjects methods are not identical. The first might return a list that contains nulls, the second will not.

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes, they represent different options - filtering out and checking for defaults before calling `Copy`.